# ²Inverse function of 2(x+1)/100 - x(x+1)/100² to build a linear distribution

Tags: functions

What's the inverse function for `y = 2(x+1)/c - x(x+1)/c²` with c being a constant such a `100`?

I am building a linear probability distribution Random, so I need an *Inverse cumulative probability distribution*:

1. [Probability distribution](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%202%2F100%20-%202x%2F100%C2%B2%20from%20x%3D0%20to%20100): `2/c - 2x/c²`
2. [Cumulative probability distribution](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+2%28x%2B1%29%2F100+-+x%28x%2B1%29%2F100%C2%B2+from+x%3D0+to+100): `2(x+1)/c - x(x+1)/c²`
3. [Inverse cumulative probability distribution according to WolfRam](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%28199-sqrt%2840401-40000+x%29%29%2F2+from+x%3D0+to+1): `(2c - 1 - sqrt((2c + 1)² -4c²x))/2`. **That's clearly wrong.** It starts at `-1` (instead of `0`) and ends at `90` instead of `100`.

What's the real inverse function of 2)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may have intended a density function of $$f(x)=\frac{2}{c}-\frac{2x}{c^2}$$ so $f(0)=f(c)=0$ (which your function in (1) does not). Its integral is: $$F(x) = \int_0^x \left(\frac{2}{c}-\frac{2y}{c^2}\right)dy = \frac{x(2c-x)}{c^2}$$ so this should be your cumulative distribution function, taking the values $F(0)=0$ and $F(c)=1$ (which your CDF in (2) does not).

Its inverse is $$F^{-1}(p)=c\left(1-\sqrt{1-p}\right)$$ so $F^{-1}(0)=0$ and $F^{-1}(1)=c$.

Comment: Yes, I intended that density function - question adjusted accordingly. Thanks for spotting that.

Comment: If uniform distribution is rank 0, linear distribution is rank 1, then I am now [trying to solve rank 2](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1007422/random-distribution-parabola-distribution-non-linear-distribution): a distribution which is not a straight line, but a parabola.