# Random distribution: Parabola distribution (non-linear distribution)

Tags: functions, probability-distributions

Thanks to [a very helpful answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/971600/%C2%B2inverse-function-of-2x1-100-xx1-100%C2%B2-to-build-a-linear-distribution), I recently successfully implemented a linear probably distribution (for my open source constraint solver) to select an element out of `k` elements:

- Density function: $$f(x)=\frac{2}{k}-\frac{2x}{k^2}$$
- Cumulative function: $$F(x) = \int_0^x \left(\frac{2}{k}-\frac{2y}{k^2}\right)dy = \frac{x(2k-x)}{k^2}$$
- Inverse cumulative function: $$F^{-1}(p)=k\left(1-\sqrt{1-p}\right)$$

Now, I need to implement **a parabolic random distribution**, with the vertex of the parabola at `(k,0)`. Something that looks like this (but the c is k):

[image: parabolic distribution]

**What's the density function of this?** Is there just 1 density function or are there multiple?

(From that density function, I 'll need to find the cumulative function and inverse cumulative function too afterwards.)

Here's what I got so far:

- Presuming a function of $$f(x) = ax² + bx + c$$
- The vertex is in (k,0), so: $$f(k) = ak² + bk + c = 0$$
- It's a distribution function, so: $$F(k) = \frac{ak³}{3} + \frac{bk²}{2} + ck = 1$$
- Given the previous 2 lines: $$a = \frac{-3bk² - 6}{4k³}$$
  which implies that there are multiple, so the density function will need an extra parameter (besides just `k`).

Comment: Do you want $f'(k)=0$ so the $x$-axis is a tangent?

Comment: Yes, so (0, k) is the vertex of the parabola. The requirement that it needs to be a tangent too, indeed eliminated the need for that extra parameter. Great observation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These questions are not difficult if you work methodically.

Your density on $[0,k]$ is proportional to $(k-x)^2$ and since $\int_0^k (k-x)^2 \, dx = \frac{k^3}{3}$, your density  must be $$f(x)=\frac{3(k-x)^2}{k^3}$$ with the cumulative distribution function $$F(x)=\frac{k^3-(k-x)^3}{k^3}=1-\left(1-\frac{x}{k}\right)^3$$ and inverse $$F^{-1}(p)=k\left( 1-{\left( 1-p\right) }^{\frac{1}{3}}\right). $$

Comment: When I try to select the 2th element (index 1) out of 100 elements, so I input `(99.0 * 99.0) * 3.0 / 1000000.0` as the p on the inverse function, I get `0.9898660171489437`, instead `1.0`. Is that a rounding error? 1% seems a bit high for a rounding error.

Comment: Trying to select the 3th (index 2), with input `(99.0 * 99.0 + 98.0 * 98.0) * 3.0 / 1000000.0` gives `1.9794226189339459` instead `2.0`. So a 2% error.

Comment: You used the density $f(x)$ when you should be using the cumulative distribution function $F(x)$.  `1-(1-1/100)^3` would give `0.029701` and `100*(1-(1-0.029701)^(1/3))` would then give `1` - no rounding here.  Similarly `1-(1-2/100)^3` would give `0.058808` and `100*(1-(1-0.058808)^(1/3))` would then give `2`

Comment: So the only reason that using the f(x) for linear distribution worked is because the average of the value of 2 discrete is actually F(x)? But for a parabolic distribution that's no longer true.

Comment: For a discrete distribution you would be using a probability mass function and sums rather than integrals to get a cumulative distribution function, and the inverse would be harder to specify.

Comment: I am using the continuous variant (inverse function) and then I simply floor the value to make it discrete. [Code is here.](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/optaplanner/blob/master/optaplanner-core/src/main/java/org/optaplanner/core/impl/heuristic/selector/common/nearby/ParabolicDistributionNearbyRandom.java#L26) My unit tests show that this good enough. Of course, if there are ways to improve it, without performance loss, I am interested :)

Comment: [I am using it for nearby selection for metaheuristics](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/droolsjbpm/optaplanner/master/optaplanner-docs/src/main/docbook/en-US/images/Chapter-Move_and_neighborhood_selection/nearbySelectionRandomDistribution.png)